# Puppeteer error Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Iam pretty new to Puppeteer (with JS).
I searched and tested a bunch of solutions, with `await` and such.
But i still can't select and click where i want to. (filling inputs is working fine) 
(PS: Iam trying to auto fill this website for personnal use) 
My code if you want to reproduce it:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 50 });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.eatthismuch.com/');

    //Menu Vege
    await page.click('#main_container > div > div.home_generator_box.container > div.row.generator_header_div > div.generator_header.col-12.col-md-10.offset-md-1.col-lg-8.offset-lg-2 > div.preset_selector_div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a')

    //Iam not sure
    page.click('#not_sure_button')

    await page.waitForNavigation();
    page.click('#c56_goal > label:nth-child(1)')
    //Prefered unit

    await page.$eval('#height-secondary', el => el.value = '180');
    await page.$eval('#weight', el => el.value = '70');
    await page.$eval('#age', el => el.value = '22');

    await browser.close();
})();
```

I want to click on the blue labels by the way :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8vEV.png

Comment: hey yo, still it's not working for you?
I ran your code in my local and it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going very good.

And there is no problem in your script as well.
You just need to `await` when you click on the `Lose weight` button.
Like this will be the final script :

```
//Menu Vege
await page.click('#main_container > div > div.home_generator_box.container > div.row.generator_header_div > div.generator_header.col-12.col-md-10.offset-md-1.col-lg-8.offset-lg-2 > div.preset_selector_div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a')

//Iam not sure
await page.click('#not_sure_button')

await page.evaluate(()=>document.querySelector('input[value=L]').click())
//Prefered unit
```

Let me know if that works. I don't see any more problem here :)

Comment: Hello ! Thanks !
It doesn't seems to work either
`(node:17204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded`
I think the issue is coming from the fact that the form is in a modal ? maybe ?

Comment: Try this. I have edited the answer with evaluate expression. It should work now :)